# Subdividing list with another list as a reference

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of seven elements:

```
list1={0,10,-20,15,-25,20,-30};
```

I have also another list of six elements:

```
div={10,15,20,15,10,5};
```

I would like to create a list subdividing the values of `list1` using values of `div list` as a reference:

```
Subdivide[0,10,10]
Subdivide[10,-20,15]
Subdivide[-20,15,20]
Subdivide[15,-25,15]
Subdivide[-25,20,10]
Subdivide[20,-30,5]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer you want can be reached this way:

```
list1=Partition[list1,2,1]
f=MapThread[Insert,{list1,div,Table[3,{Length[list1]}]}];
Apply[Subdivide,f[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[list1]]
```

Comment: Or `MapThread[subdivide[First@#1, Last@#1, #2] &, {Partition[list1, 2, 1], div}]`

Answer (score 14):

```
Subdivide @@@ Partition[Flatten@Riffle[Partition[list1, 2, 1], div], 3]
```

or

```
Subdivide @@@ Flatten /@ Transpose[{Partition[list1, 2, 1], div}]
```

or

```
Subdivide @@@ Transpose@{list1[[;; -2]], list1[[2 ;;]], div}
```

or

```
Subdivide @@@ Transpose@{Most@list1, Rest@list1, div}
```

Can it be done shorter....

Answer (score 11):

Another way:

```
MapThread[Subdivide, {Most@list1, Rest@list1, div}]
```

Comment: My fav so far, avoids the `Transpose`.

Answer (score 7):

Quite short:

```
Subdivide @@@ MapThread[Insert[##, 3] &, {Partition[list1, 2, 1], div}]
```

or crudely

```
Table[Subdivide[list1[[i]], list1[[i + 1]], div[[i]]], {i, 1, Length @ div}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Another simple solution:

```
Most[list1] + Differences[list1] Map[Subdivide, div]
```

Answer (score 5):

Also:

```
Thread@Subdivide[Most@list1, Rest@list1, div]
```

You can also use `Range` (which is `Listable` and threads over its arguments) instead of `Subdivide`.

```
Range[Most@#, Rest@#, Differences@#/#2] &[list1, div]
```

> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
>      {10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, -12, -14, -16, -18, -20},
>      {-20, -(73/4), -(33/2), -(59/4), -13, -(45/4), -(19/2), -(31/4), -6, -(17/4), -(5/
>      2), -(3/4), 1, 11/4, 9/2, 25/4, 8, 39/4, 23/2, 53/4, 15},
>      {15, 37/3, 29/3, 7, 13/3, 5/3, -1, -(11/3), -(19/3), -9, -(35/3), -(43/3), -17, -(59/3), -(67/
>      3), -25},
>     {-25, -(41/2), -16, -(23/2), -7, -(5/2), 2, 13/2, 11, 31/
>     2, 20}, {20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30}}

Answer (score 5):

```
list1 = {0, 10, -20, 15, -25, 20, -30};

div = {10, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
Subdivide @@@ Append @@@
  Transpose[{SequenceCases[list1, {_, _}, Overlaps -> True], div}]
```

returns

```
{{  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
 { 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -8, -10, -12, -14, -16, -18, -20}, 
 {-20, -(73/4), -(33/2), -(59/4), -13, -(45/4), -(19/2), -(31/4), -6, -(17/4), -(5/2), -(3/4), 1, 11/4, 9/2, 25/4, 8, 39/4, 23/2, 53/4, 15}, 
 { 15, 37/3, 29/3, 7, 13/3, 5/3, -1, -(11/3), -(19/3), -9, -(35/3), -(43/3), -17, -(59/3), -(67/3), -25}, 
 {-25, -(41/2), -16, -(23/2), -7, -(5/2), 2, 13/2, 11, 31/2, 20}, {20, 10, 0, -10, -20, -30}}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list1 = {0, 10, -20, 15, -25, 20, -30};

div = {10, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5};
```

---

Using `MovingMap`:

```
Inactive[Subdivide] @@@ Append @@@ Thread[{MovingMap[# &, list1, 1], div}]
```

[image]

Finally, use `Activate[%]` command to get result.

Answer (score 4):

```
list1 = {0, 10, -20, 15, -25, 20, -30};
div = {10, 15, 20, 15, 10, 5};

MapThread[Join, {Partition[list1, 2, 1], List /@ div}] // 
 Map[Apply[Inactive[Subdivide]]]

MapThread[
 Inactive[Subdivide] @@ PadRight[#1, 3, {#2}] &, {Partition[list1, 2, 
   1], div}]
```

---

[image]

Issue `Activate[%]` command to get result.